# Have parent window scroll before iframe starts to scroll

Tags: html, iframe

My skills with HTML is as far as just reading tutorials and trying in practice.

Here is my webpage in question - http://www.enclave-gaming.com/forum.html

I am trying to have the navigation and title area up top scroll down BEFORE my iframe begins scrolling. This way the iframe seems like it is all on one page.

If this is not making sense I understand. I am just trying to get this to work.

I will be checking up on this post as much as I can.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell you have many I have tried - Because this iframe is of a separate domain most of the code I have found (even on this site) does not work.

I am currently trying to have the page just auto scroll down upon loading but allow them to scroll up afterwards.

Even still, my goal is just to make it all like one page.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think this is possible as the scroll event will be happening in the iframe regardless of what you do. You could probably via javascript scroll your window down as the iframe scrolls, but it would go real fast. Do you have an example of what you've see and would like to do? It sounds like a poor user experience.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer.

Well according to those using my website currently, the banner up top with the navigation is annoying to them. They would like the banner to scroll down as they scroll the iframe.